# Css Sprites - Is my file too big?

Tags: css, css-sprites, sprite-sheet

I have used before different images on my webpage and now i'm coming to optimization. 
It's a dating site by the way.

What i have done is combine all images which i'm going to use into 1 image where the size is 280KB.

Now to my question: **Is that file to big?** Should i continue to have it as css sprite or should i do as i did before have small images and display them image by image?

Comment: 280 KB is huge, try to break the image into 2 or 3 files based on the use of images in the common pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fine to have a sprite upto 1 - 1.5 MB.

What's important is how many images are there in the sprite or in other terms how many HTTP requests do you save.

If you have 200KB sprite and it has only 2 images in it then it may be inefficient to use it, but if you have 5 MB sprite and there are 100 images in it then you're saving a lot of page loading time as only 1 request is made to your sprite, thereby saving 99 requests.

Comment: I have like 40 images which i'm going to use. But only like 7 are loaded when user logs in and the rest is devided on the page. Is it good then to use this spri

Comment: ok its still good, are those sprites logically related? e.g. they fall under category of icons, or slides? If yes, then leave the unused images in the sprite.

Comment: You can view my sprite here and give me your opinion =)
http://postimage.org/image/aoqazuedt/

Comment: Another factor here is TCP Slow Start. To summarize, TCP download speed starts slow and then increases the larger the file. So a larger sprite sheet has the potential to decrease requests and download speeds will be faster. There are still a number of factors affecting it...Google it for more details.